# Import error when importing python file from same directory

Tags: python, django

I have the identical problem to the question posed here:
[Django custom form ImportError even though file is in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029305/django-custom-form-importerror-even-though-file-is-in-the-same-directory)

This is from my urls.py in a django application:

```
import bulkEdit
...
...
urlpatters = patterns('',
    url(r'^engine/$', component_views.engine, name='engine'),
    ...
    url(r'^admin/', include(bulkEdit.urls)),
```

My bulkEdit.py file is in the same directory as urls.py.

The error I get is

```
  File "/home/context/work/riot/src/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named bulkEdit
```

I get the same error if I try

```
from bulkEdit import urls as bulkEditUrls
...
...
urlpatters = patterns('',
    url(r'^engine/$', component_views.engine, name='engine'),
    ...
    url(r'^admin/', include(bulkEditUrls)),
```

bulkEdit is a file in the same directory as my urls.py file; file structure is

```
Rapier
|-component
|    |-__init__.py
|    |-admin.py
|    |-forms.py
|    |-models.py
|    |-views.py
|
|-Chassis
|    |-__init__.py
|    |-urls.py
|    |-bulkEdit.py
|    |-settings.py
|    |-views.py
|
|-manage.py
```

here is what I have tried so far (In all of these cases, `'Chassis'` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`):

Using Python 2.7, so I get a syntax error with

```
import .bulkEdit
```

I've also tried:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(Chassis.bulkEdit.urls)),
```

gives me `NameError: name 'Chassis' is not defined`

```
url(r'^admin/', include("Chassis.bulkEdit.urls")),
```

gives me `ImportError: No module named urls`

```
url(r'^admin/', include("Chassis.bulkEdit")),
```

gives me `ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf <module 'Chassis.bulkEdit' from '/home/userag/work/project/src/project/Chassis/bulkEdit.pyc'> doesn't have any patterns in it`

```
url(r'^admin/', include(Chassis.bulkEdit)),
```

gives me `NameError: name 'Chassis' is not defined`

When I have

```
import bulkEdit
...
test = url(r'^admin/', include(bulkEdit.urls))
```

I get no error as long as it is not in the urlpatterns. When I add `test` to `urlpatterns`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^engine/$', component_views.engine, name='engine'),
    ...
    test
```

I get the error. Is there somewhere else I need to import bulkEdit due to me doing things with admin forms?

Comment: I get a syntax error with `import .bulkEdit`. It is a file in the same directory as urls.py

Comment: can you post your directory structure??

Answer (score 4):

Try relative import:

```
from .bulkEdit import urls as bulkEditUrls
```

Comment: I get `No module named bulkEdit`

Comment: @AG did you add dot here: [.]bulkEdit?

Comment: yes, I made sure to include the dot; I get `No module named bulkEdit`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** : After comments

try:
    url(r'^admin/', include("Chassis.bulkEdit.urls"))

but first create the bulkEdit package and in there put the urls.py files. Then copy the code in bulkEdit.py to the

```
__init__.py
```

file of the package in order to provide backward compatibility with other parts of your code.

The problem may has to do with the fact that bulkEdit.urls isn't a python module.

your dir structure after changes:

```
Rapier
|-component
|    |-__init__.py
|    |-admin.py
|    |-forms.py
|    |-models.py
|    |-views.py
|
|-Chassis
|    |-__init__.py
|    |-urls.py
|    |-bulkEdit
|        |-__init__.py     
|        |-urls.py     
|    |-settings.py
|    |-views.py
|
|-manage.py
```

Comment: If Chassis is an installed app try put it between '' characters. I mean: url(r'^admin/', include('Chassis.bulkEdit.urls')) or  url(r'^admin/', include('Chassis.bulkEdit')) one of them has to work. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Comment: (sorry, formatting is lost)In all of these cases, `'Chassis'` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`

`url(r'^admin/', include(Chassis.bulkEdit.urls)),` gives me NameError: name 'Chassis' is not defined

`url(r'^admin/', include("Chassis.bulkEdit.urls")),` gives me ImportError: No module named urls

`url(r'^admin/', include("Chassis.bulkEdit")),` gives me
ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf <module 'Chassis.bulkEdit' from '/home/userag/work/project/src/project/Chassis/bulkEdit.pyc'> doesn't have any patterns in it

`url(r'^admin/', include(Chassis.bulkEdit)),`
NameError: name 'Chassis' is not defined

Comment: After adding Chassis.bulkEdit to `INSTALLED_APPS` and creating `__init__.py` and `urls.py` inside the bulkEdit directory, I still get the error `No module named bulkEdit`. I think there is an intermediate step in django where I should be including bulkEdit, but have not.

Comment: When I do an `include("chassis.bulkEdit.urls")` in the python debugger, it shows `(<module 'chassis.bulkEdit.urls' from '/home/user/work/Rapier/src/Rapier/Chassis/bulkEdit/urls.pyc'>, None, None), so this file is able to find and recognise the bulkEdit module.

Comment: Ok, try this last thing:

    include("bulkEdit.urls")

or

    include(bulkEdit.urls)

without ""

if that dont works, I give up. :D

Comment: The problem was in my actual urls.py, it needed to know what bulkEdit was (see my answer above), but your suggestion led me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in my actual url pattern in bulkEdit/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'(?P<app_name>[^/])/(?P<model_name>[^/]+)-masschange/(?P<object_ids>[0-9,]+)/$', 'bulkEdit.mass_change_view'),)
```

should have been

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'(?P<app_name>[^/])/(?P<model_name>[^/]+)-masschange/(?P<object_ids>[0-9,]+)/$', 'Chassis.bulkEdit.bulkEdit.mass_change_view'),)
```

The error of `No module named bulkEdit` originated from here.

Answer (score 0):

But django actually imports your `bulkEdit` from other directory, and I suppose `bulkEdit` containing folder is not in `sys.path` (other option is absence of `__init__.py`), hence the error. As your application usually is in `sys.path`, you can try to specify

```
url(r'^admin/', include('Chassis.bulkEdit.urls'))
```

Comment: hhmm, when I use
`url(r'^admin/', include('Chassis.bulkEdit.urls'))`
I get a ImportError: no module named urls